# Use 'addRealmObjectField()' instead to add fields that link to other RealmObjects

Tags: java, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list, realm-migration

I have a method that creates and update a realm table

```
private static void createOrUpdateModel(RealmSchema schema, Class clazz) {
    Field field[] = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    String clazzName = clazz.getSimpleName();
    Log.e("Class name", clazzName);
    RealmObjectSchema objectSchema = schema.get(clazzName);
    if (objectSchema == null) {
        objectSchema = schema.create(clazzName);
        Log.e("Created :", clazzName);
    }

    for (Field mField: field) {
 
        if (!objectSchema.hasField(mField.getName())) {   
           objectSchema.addField(mField.getName(), mField.getType());
          
            Log.e(mField.getName().concat(" "), mField.getType().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}
```

But in one of the fields in my table is a realmObject. This is the model class

```
public class NimcKeyDetailsModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String applicationId;
    private String credentialData;
    private CenterModel centerModel;
}
```

CenterModel is a realm object. now I am getting this error

> Use 'addRealmObjectField()' instead to add fields that link to other RealmObjects: centerModel(class com.seamfix.nimc_sdk.models.CenterModel)

So what I did was to check if the field type is of type realmObject then I use the addRealmObjectField() if not then addField. But still didn't work, please is there a workaround this?

Comment: It's not clear what the code in the top part of the question has to do with the that model. It's also not clear where that error is being thrown. Can you update and clarify the *question* please?

Comment: Okay, so I create or update this NimcKeyDetailsModel with the createOrUpdate method, so when it gets to the part of adding the centerModel field which is also of type realmObject the app crashes with this error:  Use 'addRealmObjectField()' instead to add fields that link to other RealmObjects: centerModel(class com.seamfix.nimc_sdk.models.CenterModel)

Comment: There is no code in the question that references *adding the centerModel field* so we won't be able to help. It's a good idea to do troubleshooting before posting questions; step through the code line by line, examining the vars and execution along the way or add print statements to output the vars. When you spot something unexpected, include that in the question. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)